# request.resource object in the context of read request to firestore with the security rule

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Firestore documentation mentions this security rule in their document to fix the insecure rule [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules)!

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow only authenticated content owners access
    match /some_collection/{document} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author_uid
    }
  }
}
```

What is the value of request.resource.data in the context of read request to the firestore? Will this rule be valid for read requests?

From what I understand resource.data is something that should be utilized for read rules as it represents data in the firestore database. Isn't request.resource null for read requests?

Answer (score 2):

The `request.resource` variable is defined as the resource as it will (might) exist after the request has completed.

Since a `read` rules doesn't modify the data, in that case the `request.resource.data` will be exactly the same as `resource.data`.

I typically would separate `read` rules from `write` rules if I find myself needing to access `request.resource` as it is indeed not as intuitive there.