# What will the "request.resource.data" contain if I only update a single field of a document among several fields in firestore database?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Suppose, I have several fields in the *favorites* document and it looks like below:

```
{
favorites:
   {
      "color": "Red",
      "place": "ocean",
      "time": "morning"
   }
}
```

Now, I want to update a single field in this document. If I write the below code to update a single field, will the **request.resource.data** contain only this field or will it also contain the other fields in this document?

```
db.collection("users")
  .document("favorites")
  .update({
    "color": "Red"
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `request.resource` variable contains the document as it'll exist after the update, if that update is allowed.

So `request.resource.data` contains your updated `color` and the `place` and `time` values from the existing document.

Comment: Can you give any reference?

Comment: Why? Do you get a behavior that doesn't match with my description?
Anyway: previous references: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57105005/request-resource-object-in-the-context-of-read-request-to-firestore-with-the-sec/57105134#57105134, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69597616/is-resource-data-and-request-resource-data-the-same-thing/69599338#69599338 and from there https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation

Comment: No, I didn't get any such behavior that violates your explanation. I just wanted to read some official documents which I didn't find while searching online.